# Create attribute in PHP by selecting tag name

Tags: php, html, attributes, element

I am trying to load html, find a tag and add an attribute to it, before showing it.

I have tried:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$domDocument->loadHTML("<html><body>Test<br></body></html>");
$domElement = $domDocument->getElementsByTagName('body');

foreach ($domElement as $formula) {
    $formula->nodeValue->createAttribute('name')->value = 'attributevalue';
}

libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
```

But I have this error:

> Call to a member function createAttribute() on string

Do you have a solution please ?

Best regards

Comment: I think createAttribute can only be run on an object and nodeValue is a string, not an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nodeValue returns the String type, which isn't the way to create an attribute.

And in fact, the node's type is DOMElement, so you need to set the attribute as similar as the following code:

```
<?php
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML("<html><body>Test<br></body></html>");
$domElement = $domDocument->getElementsByTagName('body');
foreach ($domElement as $formula) {
    $formula->setAttribute("name", "attributevalue");
}
?>
```

Comment: If I remove nodeValue, I have this error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::createAttribute()

Comment: I have written a demo :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("<html><body>Test<br></body></html>");
$domElements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body');
foreach ($domElements as $domElement) {
    $domAttribute = $doc->createAttribute('name');
    $domAttribute->value = 'attributevalue';
    $domElement->appendChild($domAttribute);
    print_r($domElement->getAttribute('name'));
    // returns attributevalue
}
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
```

Try it out [@PHP-Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1e183597a613feafa0215d56123510374305a637)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution where [setAttribute](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php) is used instead of create. Though I am not sure the purpose of the loop since there is usually only 1 body tag.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$domDocument->loadHTML("<html><body>Test<br></body></html>");
$domElement = $domDocument->getElementsByTagName('body');

foreach ($domElement as $formula) {
    $formula->setAttribute('name', 'thevalue');
}

libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
```

Comment: The body tag was just a example ;)

Comment: Ah OK, that makes more sense then. I was not sure if you were wanting to target the children of the body which would require another modification if that were the case.